# How to make hot code replace in eclipse work without building automatically?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, hotdeploy

The [Eclipse Wiki](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_hot_code_replace%3F) says:

> If HCR does not work for you [...] you may not have automatic building turned on. Make sure that 'Project > Build Automatically' is checked.

Building the project I'm working on takes quite some time. Therefore I'd like to control when the build is triggered which is why I unchecked 'Project > Build Automatically'.

Is it possible to manually trigger hot code replace (HCR) without having automatic building enabled?

Eclipse says [on its website](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/platform-core/documents/scoped_builds.html) that

> Project > Build All (Ctrl+B) can be invoked at any time to trigger what auto-build was doing automatically.

I tried to use that to trigger HCR, but when I debug, change some code and press Ctrl+B as in the quote above, no HCR is performed but the whole project is build.

Comment: Eclipse compiles incrementally, which should not take long, even for large and many dependent projects. Why is it slow in your case? Are you using an outdated Eclipse version or do you have code generation? In some cases an installed plug-in may also be the cause. Ctrl+B does not trigger a full build, but an incremental build since the last build. Only _Project > Clean_ triggers a full build. Something seems wrong with your project or with your Eclipse installation.

Comment: The projects are Maven projects and were imported as such into Eclipse. I guess Eclipse therefore uses Maven to build the projects, doesn't it? Even a not-full build takes a long time, even if only one class changed. I think this is due to [this](https://users.maven.apache.narkive.com/FAqDGEfS/avoiding-overwriting-newer-file-when-using-maven-resources-plugin-copy-resources-with-filtering) Maven behaviour which results in resources being copied and therefore (at least I guess it has to do with the "new" resources) jars being packed although in lots of projects nothing has changed. 1/2

Comment: I agree that something should be done to tackle this, but for now I'd like to know if triggering HCR manually is possible, too. Building in paralllel helps to speed things up, but doesn't work [reliably](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-6843) for all projects. 2/2

Comment: Also in Maven projects, the incremental Eclipse compiler is used to compile on Ctrl+B. `javac` which is used by Maven by default would be too slow for that. The idea is that everything up to compilation is done on Ctrl+B, and everything that comes after that, such as packaging to a JAR, only when doing a (slow) Maven build. In your case, it seems something of your `pom.xml` is done on Ctrl+B by mistake, which is probably the root cause of your issue. For more details see: https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/m2e-execution-not-covered.html#execute-plugin-goal

Comment: Thanks a lot for this information, I wasn't aware! I will look into this!